# How to show different query results from the same dataset?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a lot of data in gsheets. From that data, I have to make a different report day by day.

I want to make a report that contains name and color. Only two data would be reported, but the data must be different everyday. Example of the data showed below.

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Book | Blue |
| Sky | Blue |
| Table | Blue |
| Pencil | Blue |
| Pen | Blue |
| Bike | Blue |

Today, I want to report Book and Sky with their color. Tomorrow, I want to report Table and Pencil with their color too.
Using the query function, how I get that report table automatically?